# footage surfaces of someone/something

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> footage surfaces of someone/something

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The common news idiom “footage surfaces” means that video has come to public attention, usually online through social media.

For example, somebody can record video of a newsworthy event like an attack or a demonstration. They might then take days to upload it to social media (eg: YouTube) and then it can take weeks to come to the attention of news outlets. The news outlets then publish the video (“footage”) with a description like, “Footage has surfaced of the attack which occurred last month in the disputed territory of Trelvia.” In *headlinese* this might be abbreviated as:

> Footage surfaces of Trelvia attack

Here **footage** generally means a bit of electronically recorded video but originally meant, "the length of film used to record a scene, event, etc.,"

**Surfaces** is used figuratively to refer to something “floating to the surface” so that it comes to our attention.

Comment: Examples: https://www.abc.net.au/news/2019-09-23/video-uyghurs-shaved-blindfolded-xinjiang-train-station-china/11537628.   https://www.irishpost.com/news/racial-abuse-luas-173546